# DateRangesOverlap always returns all results

Tags: caml-query, spquery

I have a problem with SPQuery and DataRangesOverlap.

In my calendar there are three events that don't happen today.
In SPQuery.query I want to exclude these events.
Unfortunately all events are returned. The contains filter for a text column works fine but the DataRangesOverlap doesn't do any filtering. Here is my code:

```
SPListCollection oLists = oSiteCollection.AllWebs["MYSITE"].Lists;
String res = "";
SPQuery spquery = new SPQuery();
string datasel = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(caldata.SelectedDate.Date);

spquery.Query = "<Where><And><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" /><FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\" /><FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\" IncludeTimeValue=\"True\">Today</Value></DateRangesOverlap><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + tbnome.Text + "</Value></Contains></Or></And></Where>";
spquery.ExpandRecurrence = true;
spquery.RowLimit = 100;


foreach (SPList l in oLists)  {
  String title =  l.Title;
  if (title.IndexOf("MyCalendar")==0)  {

    SPListItemCollection items = l.GetItems(spquery);

    foreach (SPListItem item in items)
    {
      res += "<li>" + item["Title"]  + " date1 " + item["Start Time"] + " date2 " + item["End Time"] + "</li>";
    }
  }
}
res = "<ul>"+res+"</ul>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote

```
<Value Type=\"DateTime\" IncludeTimeValue=\"True\">Today</Value>
```

instead of

```
<Value Type=\"DateTime\" IncludeTimeValue=\"True\"><Today /></Value>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the caml date stuff pretty much sucks in SharePoint.  It won't compare based on time and I think the daterangesoverlap only works for recurring events.  Are the events you expect NOT to be shown recurring or single instance events?